# Scrapy splash response won't return complete html

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape this link https://www.myntra.com/women-kurtas-kurtis-suits . But when in try to render it through splash http API. I get this below partially rendered result [image]

Am I missing something here ?

This is the actual page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to scrape products, why don't you use the non JS rendered HTML returned by default? You will find JSON objects containing products details inside it. Here's an example from the web page you posted:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json"> {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":"AKS Women Blue & Grey Printed Kurta with Palazzos","image":"http://assets.myntassets.com/assets/images/8076903/2018/12/8/fb0cf882-a473-4aae-86c2-edf912b70b6e1544251004970-AKS-Women-Kurta-Sets-2261544251003921-1.jpg","description":"Women Printed Kurta with Palazzos","brand":{"@type":"Thing"},"offers":{"@type":"Offer","priceCurrency":"INR","price":989},"AggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","itemReviewed":"AKS Women Blue & Grey Printed Kurta with Palazzos","ratingCount":0,"reviewCount":""}}</script>
```

Using JSON Python library, you can extract the data and use it as you want.

Comment: But, I need to get the product url and also scrapy through the pages.

Comment: @Amar The product URL and other data are found as JSON as well in a JavaScript variable called "window.__myx". You can find it by searching the source code for the webpage. You could easily scrape it, convert its content to JSON and extract the data you want.

Comment: @Amar The same variable could be found after scraping the product link without JS rendering, containing more details about the product. You can use a standard library like "requests" to scrape both the category link and the products links.

Comment: Answer is providing an alternative rather than solving/helping with the issue.